# C/C++において、変数定義のみの場合はNilとなるのか？

Tags: c++, c

現在、 [ALDS1_8_A](https://onlinejudge.u-aizu.ac.jp/courses/lesson/1/ALDS1/8/ALDS1_8_A)を行っています。2分探索木です。

解答コードは、以下のような形です。

insert関数の中で、`x`を現在の比べるノード,`y`を親のノード,`z`を挿入するノード
として考えていると思うのですが、xに対して初期値の`root`ポインタを入れている挙動が分かりません。
具体的には、While文の条件文です。
`x`が`Nil`ではない条件だと思うのですが、そもそもxに最初から`Nil`なんて入っているのでしょうか？
xに入っている初期の値は、Nilではなく`root`だと思います。
`root`は、Nodeポインタ型だと思うのですが、`root`は`Nil`ではないと思います。
C/C++では、変数は定義したが実際にはその中に値が入っていない場合は`Nil`となるのでしょうか？

ご教授よろしくお願い致します。

```
struct Node {
  int key;
  Node *right, *left;
};

Node *root, *NIL;

void insert(int k) {
  Node *y = NIL;
  Node *x = root;
  Node *z;

  z = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  z->key = k;
  z->left = NIL;
  z->right = NIL;

  while ( x != NIL ) {
    y = x;
    if ( z->key < x->key )
      x = x->left;
    else
      x = x->right;
  }

  if ( y == NIL ) {
    root = z;
  } else {
    if ( z->key < y->key )
      y->left = z;
    else
      y->right = z;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```cpp
Node *root, *NIL;
```

`root`、`NIL` はグローバル変数なので、初期値は 0 になります。よって、ローカル変数 `x` も `y` も初期値は 0 です。`NIL` との比較は 0 と比較していることになります。

---

C言語のまともなコードなら、`NIL` という変数は作らずに `NULL` を使うのが普通でしょう。C++のまともなコードなら、`NIL` という変数は作らずに `nullptr` を使うのが普通でしょう。

Comment: int32_t様　ご回答ありがとうございます。　`root` や `NIL` は、`Node` 型のグローバル変数なのに初期値は0なのでしょうか？　もしこれらが、int型であったら初期値が0ということはわかるのですが、構造体やクラスであっても、イニシャライズしていなかったら初期値は0なのでしょうか？　ご教授よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 構造体でも全フィールドが0です。この場合は`Node`型ではなく`Node*`型なので、0のポインタ値です。

Comment: グローバル（静的）の場合に限り各フィールドの初期値 `0` なことには注意してね。局所変数 (自動変数) の初期値は不定であって `0` とは限らないです。またフィールドの初期値 `0` をもってオブジェクトの初期化済みと考えると誤りますのでその辺も理解が必要です。この質問においては `NIL` や `root` がオブジェクトではない（単なるポインタ）であることが重要。

Comment: 言語仕様に基づいて厳密にいうとポインタ型については 0 ではなく「空ポインタ」です。 無効 (オブジェクトや関数を指さない) なポインタであることを表すなんらかの状態であって整数の 0 との互換性は限定的です。